# Thread Error - Thread 1 :Breakpoint1.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am attaching the following program code for displaying the real values of fractions and the build is successful but the program crashes with the thread error. Can you please tell me, where is it that Iam making a mistake. The help would really be appreciated.
Thanks
Maverick10

```
#import<Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Fraction : NSObject
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator; // variables to be used
}
-(void) print;
-(void) setNumerator:(int) n;
-(void) setDenominator:(int) d;
-(int) numerator;
-(int) denominator;
-(double) convertToNum; // new method declared
@end

@implementation Fraction
-(void) print
{
NSLog(@"%i/%i",numerator,denominator);
}
-(void) setNumerator :(int) n
{
numerator=n;
}
-(void) setDenominator :(int)d
{
denominator=d;
}
-(int)numerator
{
return numerator;
}
-(int) denominator
{
return denominator;
}
-(double) convertToNum
{
if(denominator!=0) // checking for denominator to be non zero
return (double) numerator/denominator;
else
return NAN;
}
@end
//Program Section
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[ NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Fraction * aFraction =[[Fraction alloc] init];
    Fraction * bFraction =[[Fraction alloc] init];

    [aFraction setNumerator:1]; // setting the numerator for the first fraction.Similarly denominator
    [aFraction setDenominator:4];
    [aFraction print];
    NSLog(@"= ");
    NSLog(@"%g",[aFraction convertToNum]);

    [bFraction print];
          NSLog(@"="); 
    NSLog(@"%g",[bFraction convertToNum]);

    [aFraction release];
    [bFraction release];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just ran your program in Xcode and it worked fine. What thread error did you get?

Comment: I got this error - Thread 1:Breakpoint1.1 in the line where i define -(void) setNumerator:(int)n - method. The output i get is lldb.

Comment: I suspect you accidentally added a breakpoint there. If you look to the left of -(void)setNumerator, do you see a blue rectangular arrow pointing at it?

Comment: yes, you are right. Thank you for the help, i simply deleted the breakpoint. But how is it that i added a breakpoint, even without intending to do so ??

Answer (score 0):

You get Thread1:Breakpoint1.1 because you added a breakpoint at -(void)setNumerator. You probably just accidentally clicked on that space to add the break point.